# Keep UITextField as first responder when pushing new view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield, first-responder

Is there any way to keep a `UITextField` first responder even as I push another view controller?

Essentially, I'm taking a screenshot of the screen, using that screenshot in the new view controller, and then popping the second view controller. The issue, though, is that it isn't a smooth transition; when the view controller pops, the keyboard in the picture disappears (since the picture was in the second view controller but has since been popped), but the actual keyboard hasn't reappeared yet. You see the keyboard sliding up just after the picture disappears. Is there anyway to prevent this such that the keyboard is just always there?

I don't have any other `UITextField`s in the new view controller, only the screenshot, a `UIButton`, `UIScrollView`, and two `UIGestureRecognizer`s.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it's all the same, why not animate the views in and out yourself.  That way you retain first responder status without popping the VC off the navigation stack.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Use core animation to make a UIView slide on and off the screen instead of pushing a completely new view controller.  It's easy, I can show you if you'd like.